# Is there a way to access javascript variables within jinja2 template braces?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a flask route

```
@app.route('/another/<int:value>')
def another():
    return 'another'
```

Using javascript, I'm trying to access the url for this `route` using `url_for` within jinja2 template braces

```
<script>
    const v = 1;
    const sample = "{{url_for('another', value=v)}}";
</script>
```

doing this raises an error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'v' is undefined`.
I suspect `v` is outside the scope of the jinja templates.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Jinja runs server-side while JavaScript runs on the client. A combination in this way is not possible because the variable does not yet exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yeah, it does